# prefetch_related for multiple Levels

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

If my Models look like:

```
class Publisher(models.Model):
    pass

class Book(models.Model):
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)

class Page(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
```

and I would like to get the queryset for `Publisher` I do `Publisher.object.all()`.
If then want to make sure to prefetch I can do:

```
Publisher.objects.all().prefetch_related('book_set')`
```

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to do this prefetching using `select_related` or
   must I use `prefetch_related`?
2. Is there a way to prefetch the
   `page_set`? This does not work:

`Publisher.objects.all().prefetch_related('book_set', 'book_set_page_set')`

Answer (score 66, accepted):

1. No, you cannot use `select_related` for a reverse relation. `select_related` does a SQL join, so a single record in the main queryset needs to reference exactly one in the related table (`ForeignKey` or `OneToOne` fields). `prefetch_related` actually does a totally separate second query, caches the results, then "joins" it into the queryset in python. So it is needed for `ManyToMany` or reverse `ForeignKey` fields.
2. Have you tried two underscores to do the multi level prefetches? Like this: `Publisher.objects.all().prefetch_related('book_set', 'book_set__page_set')`

Comment: 1. If `Page` has a `OneToOne` field to `TextContent`, would it be: `...prefetch_related('book_set__page_set__text_contents')` or `...select_related('book_set__page_set__text_contents')`

Comment: I believe it would be the second version.

Answer (score 75):

Since Django 1.7, instances of `django.db.models.Prefetch` class can be used as an argument of `.prefetch_related`. `Prefetch` object constructor has a `queryset` argument that allows to specify nested multiple levels prefetches like that:

```
Project.objects.filter(
        is_main_section=True
    ).select_related(
        'project_group'
    ).prefetch_related(
        Prefetch(
            'project_group__project_set',
            queryset=Project.objects.prefetch_related(
                Prefetch(
                    'projectmember_set',
                    to_attr='projectmember_list'
                )
            ),
            to_attr='project_list'
        )
    )
```

It is stored into attributes with `_list` suffix because I use `ListQuerySet` to process prefetch results (filter / order).

Comment: This is a really brilliant answer and lets you save a lot on db traffic. I don't understand why this answer didn't get much attention

Comment: See https://github.com/Dmitri-Sintsov/django-jinja-knockout/search?q=ListQuerySet&unscoped_q=ListQuerySet

Comment: Hi @DmitriySintsov Can I please get your help here:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68682472/api-endpoint-for-django-group-model-generating-excess-number-of-queries

Comment: -1. The solution here uses unknown models and an unknown structure. It would be much easier to understand if you used the models that OP provided, or explain the structure of your project example. Very happy to undo the -1 if we get that clarity.