# select_related after prefetch_related

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

My Models looks like:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher) # This is not important

class Baz(models.Model):
    a = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Page(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    baz = models.ForeignKey(Baz)
```

And I am trying to run a query like this:

```
[[x.baz.a for x in y.page_set.all()]
for y in Book.objects.all().prefetch_related('page_set', 'page_set__baz')]
```

Which I think the ORM should be able to perform as two queries: (`Page JOIN Baz`) and `Book`. The final join should occur in Python. Instead I see the ORM executing three queries. I believe that I have to some how use `select_related`, but this does not work either (nor does moving `select_related` before `prefetch_related`):

```
Book.objects.all().prefetch_related('page_set', 'page_set__baz').select_related('page_set__baz')
```

The queries (`uploads` is the app):

```
QUERY = u'SELECT "uploads_book"."id", "uploads_book"."publisher_id" FROM "uploads_book"' - PARAMS = (); args=()
QUERY = u'SELECT "uploads_page"."id", "uploads_page"."book_id", "uploads_page"."baz_id" FROM "uploads_page" WHERE "uploads_page"."book_id" IN (%s, %s)' - PARAMS = (1, 2); args=(1, 2)
QUERY = u'SELECT "uploads_baz"."id", "uploads_baz"."a" FROM "uploads_baz" WHERE "uploads_baz"."id" IN (%s)' - PARAMS = (1,); args=(1,)
```

This is related to the comment here: [prefetch_related for multiple Levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27116770/prefetch-related-for-multiple-levels#comment42737662_27117246)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54569384

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try to use [`Prefetch` object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch)

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

page_qs = Page.objects.select_related('baz')
books = Book.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('page_set', queryset=page_qs))
```