# Django chaining prefetch_related and select_related

Tags: django, django-models, prefetch

Let's say I have following models

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    ...

class Prop(models.Model):
    ...

class Bar(models.Model):
    foo: models.ForeignKey(Foo, related_name='bars', ...)
    prop: models.ForeignKey(Prop, ...)
```

Now I want to make the following query.

```
foos = Foo.objects.prefetch_related('bars__prop').all()
```

Does the above query makes 3 Database calls or only 2 (select_related for `prop` from `bar`), given that only one `prop` is associated with `bar`

If it takes 3 calls then, is there a way to make it 2 calls by using selected_related for `bar -> prop`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27121331

Answer (score 20):

You can use the [`Prefetch`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch) class to specify the queryset that is used in `prefetch_related()` and this way combine it with `select_related()`:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch
bars = Bar.objects.select_related('prop')
foos = Foo.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('bars', queryset=bars)).all()
```

Note that this should be two queries, one for the `Foo` objects and one for getting the related `Bar` objects that are being joined in the same query with `Prop`.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use [Prefetch](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects) class along with [prefetch_related_objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related-objects)

```
foos = Foo.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('bars', queryset=Bars.objects.all()))
prefetch_related_objects(foos,'bars__props')
```

You can validate wether the results are prefetched properly by using the below commands

```
 print(foos[0]._prefetched_objects_cache)
 print(foos[0].bars.all()[0]._state.fields_cache)
```

Comment: I don't believe that the `prefetch_related_objects()` call is needed if we haven't retrieved the Foo objects before the `prefetch_related(Prefetch('bars'...))` filter was attached to the QuerySet.  I ran your validation statements (very cool!) w/o it and it showed everything properly in the cache.