# how can I get a query set from multiple levels of sets / foreign keys?

Tags: python, django

If A contains a set of B and B contains a set of C, then I am looking for a way to start with A and end up with a query set of C.

A simple example:

```py
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)


class Page(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)


class Paragraph(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()
    page = models.ForeignKey(Page)


def query():
    books = Book.objects.all()\
       .prefetch_related('page_set', 'page_set__paragraph_set')

    for book in books:
        pages = book.page_set

        # I need to do something like this
        paragraphs = pages.all().paragraph_set
        # invalid

        # or
        paragraphs = book.page_set.select_related('paragraph_set')
        # valid, but paragraphs is still a QuerySet of Pages

        # this works, but results in one query for EVERY book,
        # which is what I need to avoid
        paragraphs = Paragraph.objects.filter(page__book=book)


        # do stuff with the book
        #...


        # do stuff with the paragraphs in the book
        # ...
```

How do I get a query set of paragraphs from just a Book instance?

The named args syntax for Django queries supports an infinite level of nesting of sets/foreign key relationships, but I can't find a way to use the ORM mapping to actually get a related query set from the top-down.

And getting query-set from the bottom-up negates the benefits of `prefetch_related`/`select_related`.

The above example is a simplified version of what I need to do in my application. The database has thousands of "Books" and any n + 1 queries must be avoided.

I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27116770/prefetch-related-for-multiple-levels) about using prefetch across multiple levels, but the answer didn't address how to actually obtain the fetched query set for use.

Comment: Just to be clear, you don't want the bottom-up approach like this: `Paragraph.objects.filter(page__book=the_book_instance)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you've done the prefetch, it seems like the only cheap way to access the child records is through `all()`. Any filters seem to trigger another database query.

The short answer to your question about all the paragraphs in a book is to use a list comprehension with two levels:

```
    paragraphs = [paragraph
                  for page in book.page_set.all()
                  for paragraph in page.paragraph_set.all()]
```

Here's a runnable example:

```
# Tested with Django 1.11.13
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import sys

import django
from django.apps import apps
from django.apps.config import AppConfig
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile, File
from django.db import connections, models, DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS
from django.db.models.base import ModelBase

from django_mock_queries.mocks import MockSet, mocked_relations

NAME = 'udjango'


def main():
    setup()

    class Book(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    class Page(models.Model):
        number = models.IntegerField()
        book = models.ForeignKey(Book)

    class Paragraph(models.Model):
        number = models.IntegerField()
        page = models.ForeignKey(Page)

    syncdb(Book)
    syncdb(Page)
    syncdb(Paragraph)

    b = Book.objects.create(name='Gone With The Wind')
    p = b.page_set.create(number=1)
    p.paragraph_set.create(number=1)
    b = Book.objects.create(name='The Three Body Problem')
    p = b.page_set.create(number=1)
    p.paragraph_set.create(number=1)
    p.paragraph_set.create(number=2)
    p = b.page_set.create(number=2)
    p.paragraph_set.create(number=1)
    p.paragraph_set.create(number=2)

    books = Book.objects.all().prefetch_related('page_set',
                                                'page_set__paragraph_set')

    for book in books:
        print(book.name)
        paragraphs = [paragraph
                      for page in book.page_set.all()
                      for paragraph in page.paragraph_set.all()]
        for paragraph in paragraphs:
            print(paragraph.page.number, paragraph.number)


def setup():
    DB_FILE = NAME + '.db'
    with open(DB_FILE, 'w'):
        pass  # wipe the database
    settings.configure(
        DEBUG=True,
        DATABASES={
            DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS: {
                'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
                'NAME': DB_FILE}},
        LOGGING={'version': 1,
                 'disable_existing_loggers': False,
                 'formatters': {
                    'debug': {
                        'format': '%(asctime)s[%(levelname)s]'
                                  '%(name)s.%(funcName)s(): %(message)s',
                        'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'}},
                 'handlers': {
                    'console': {
                        'level': 'DEBUG',
                        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                        'formatter': 'debug'}},
                 'root': {
                    'handlers': ['console'],
                    'level': 'WARN'},
                 'loggers': {
                    "django.db": {"level": "DEBUG"}}})
    app_config = AppConfig(NAME, sys.modules['__main__'])
    apps.populate([app_config])
    django.setup()
    original_new_func = ModelBase.__new__

    @staticmethod
    def patched_new(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        if 'Meta' not in attrs:
            class Meta:
                app_label = NAME
            attrs['Meta'] = Meta
        return original_new_func(cls, name, bases, attrs)
    ModelBase.__new__ = patched_new


def syncdb(model):
    """ Standard syncdb expects models to be in reliable locations.

    Based on https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9.3
    /django/core/management/commands/migrate.py#L285
    """
    connection = connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS]
    with connection.schema_editor() as editor:
        editor.create_model(model)

main()
```

And here's the end of the output. You can see that it only runs one query for each table.

```
2018-10-30 15:58:25[DEBUG]django.db.backends.execute(): (0.000) SELECT "udjango_book"."id", "udjango_book"."name" FROM "udjango_book"; args=()
2018-10-30 15:58:25[DEBUG]django.db.backends.execute(): (0.000) SELECT "udjango_page"."id", "udjango_page"."number", "udjango_page"."book_id" FROM "udjango_page" WHERE "udjango_page"."book_id" IN (1, 2); args=(1, 2)
2018-10-30 15:58:25[DEBUG]django.db.backends.execute(): (0.000) SELECT "udjango_paragraph"."id", "udjango_paragraph"."number", "udjango_paragraph"."page_id" FROM "udjango_paragraph" WHERE "udjango_paragraph"."page_id" IN (1, 2, 3); args=(1, 2, 3)
Gone With The Wind
1 1
The Three Body Problem
1 1
1 2
2 1
2 2
```

Comment: thanks. I had cobbled together something similar, but the double `for` list comprehension is much cleaner than what I had. The only issue with this and @SamMason answer is that the result is a list and not a `QuerySet`. In my specific use, I'm passing this result to another method that expects a QuerySet parameter with methods like `.count()`, and `.filter()`. But after doing some research it looks like there is no way to append to a QuerySet, and combining QuerySets via `|` or `union()` calls the internal `_clone()` method, which does not copy the cache. So future operations re-run the query.

Comment: You can use duck typing, @BrianHVB. Write a class that holds the list of paragraph objects, and has `.count()` and `.filter()` methods that operate on that list. I've used the [django-mock-queries library](https://github.com/stphivos/django-mock-queries) for running Django tests without a database, but you could use a simpler version to stick to your cached data. However, it's probably simpler to modify the method that is expecting a QuerySet so that it will accept a list.

Answer (score 1):

further to Don's answer, you can use `Prefetch` objects to apply any filters you want, e.g:

```
from django.db import models, connection

def query():
    paragraph_filter = models.Prefetch(
        'page_set__paragraph_set',
        Paragraph.objects.filter(number__gt=1))

    books = Book.objects.all().prefetch_related(
        'page_set', paragraph_filter)

    for book in books:
        for page in book.page_set.all():
            for paragraph in page.paragraph_set.all():
                print(paragraph)

    print(connection.queries)
```

Django takes care of ensuring that all appropriate objects gets loaded in a small number of queries (one per table, so you'll get three queries)