# Django: Select matching foreign keys during filter

Tags: django, django-queryset

We have the following example models and are wondering if it's possible to select the foreign keys that match during the same query, possibly as an annotation.

```
class BaseProduct(models.Model):
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sub_title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    identifier_retailer = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    has_multiple_variants = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class BaseProductVariant(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(BaseProduct)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    sub_title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, help_text='Product description')
    features = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, help_text='One feature per line')
    content = RedactorField(allow_image_upload=True, allow_file_upload=True, blank=True, null=True, help_text='Use this for rich HTML on featured products')
    warranty_string = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    identifier_retailer = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    identifier_upc = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    identifier_model = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

We can query the results easily with `BaseProduct.objects.filter()...` but would like to select the list of matching BaseProductVariant's at the same time, otherwise we have to query the database in an unconventional fashion, and joining in python with `prefetch_related` on `BaseProductVariant.objects.filter(product__in=[]).prefetch_related(product)`, `select_related` works on this too, but it a bit slower due to the extra deserialization on each row.

Comment: What do you mean "the foreign keys that match"? What's wrong with directly doing `BaseProduct.objects.filter().prefetch_related(baseproductvariant)`?

Comment: So anyone also seeing this, you can do a Prefetch (of a Prefetch) since Django 1.7. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44845453/568508

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `prefetch_related` from `BaseProduct` to prefetch the variants with the related name. You can also use the `Prefetch`[1] object from `django.db.models` to control the attribute name where the prefetched variants end up:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

products_with_variants = BaseProduct.objects.all().prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('baseproductvariant_set', to_attr='variants'))

for p in products_with_variants:
    print(p.variants)
```

[1] https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch