# How to use multiple model in froms Django class based view and render fields value in html templates?

Tags: python, django

I have two model post and HeaderImage. I want use both of model in my html froms. here is my code:

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=300,unique=True,error_messages={'unique':"This title already exists. Please use different title"})
     author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
class HeaderImage(models.Model): 
     header_image = models.ImageField() #I want to merge this model with Post model and want to add image field in my current forms.
```

**froms.py**

```
class BlogPost(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
      model = Post
      fields = ['title','author','body']
```

**views.py**

```
class BlogUpdateView(PermissionRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
      raise_exception = True
      permission_required = "blog.change_post"
      model = Post
      template_name = "blog_update_post.html"
      form_class = BlogPost
```

How to get image filed from second model and add it to existing from which using first model?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27117246/11360069) is, may be help you!

Comment: add new image field to BlogPost and override save function to create/update HeaderImage

Comment: Pavan Kumar can you please show an example