# API endpoint for django `Group` model generating excess number of queries

Tags: django, query-optimization, django-queryset, django-orm, django-select-related

I am trying to build an endpoint for the default django's `Group` model, which has `name` and `permissions` fields:- Here are my view and serializers:-

Serializers.py:-

```py
class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'permissions')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        permissions = validated_data.pop('permissions')
        instance = self.instance or self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        instance.full_clean()
        instance.save()
        instance.permissions.add(*permissions)
        return instance

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        if 'permissions' in validated_data:
            permissions = validated_data.pop('permissions')
            instance.permissions.clear()
            instance.permissions.add(*permissions)
        instance.full_clean()
        return super().update(instance, validated_data)
```

Views.py:-

```py
class GroupListCreateView(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Group.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GroupSerializer


class GroupDetailView(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Group.objects.order_by('name')
    serializer_class = GroupSerializer
```

with this serializers, and views I am facing a issue which is known as N+1 issue, that is the number of queries is really shooting high:-

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can I please get any help on this.

Group & Permission model is the default model which comes with django(copy pasting it):-

```
class Group(models.Model):
    objects: GroupManager

    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    permissions = models.ManyToManyField(Permission)

class Permission(models.Model):
    content_type_id: int
    objects: PermissionManager

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    codename = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Referencing the model in the docs:- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/auth/#permission-model

Comment: Can you share your *related* models (so `Group` and `Permission` I guess)?

Comment: Updated the question, have a look